# Check maximum date and keep that row only

Tags: python, date, max, lines-of-code

I have a df with several duplicated values in column B.

What I need is to look for the most recent date of column A for each value in column B and relove the lines that are not the most recent:

```
A            B          E
26/12/2023  apple         7,9
26/12/2022  apple         8,3
26/12/2023  pear          28,6
26/12/2022  orange        33,3
26/12/2023  wildberry     24,7
26/12/2022  wildberry     29,1
26/12/2023  grapes        17,1
```

The result should be :

```
A            B          E
26/12/2023  apple          7,9
26/12/2023  pear          28,6
26/12/2022  orange        33,3
26/12/2023  wildberry     24,7
26/12/2023  grapes        17,1
```

Could you help me find the correct formula? I am a beginner and got lost in a loc function

I am a beginner and got lost in a loc function

Comment: You should add a [mre] of what you tried and a python representation of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by:

```
df.groupby('B')['A'].max()
```

https://scales.arabpsychology.com/stats/how-to-find-the-max-value-by-group-in-pandas/

Comment: Thanks! The groupby worked! I ended up using the following function: df1 =df[df.groupby('Article')['DATE PUB'].transform('max') == df['DATE PUB']]

Comment: Great to hear I could help you out